# What are Best practices for delivering user-generated content sharing service globally from Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, regional

What are the issues for using Amazon S3 to store user-uploaded photos and video and delivering these to users around the world. One user's uploads may be viewed by users in any location. Is this the use-case for using Amazon CloudFront?

We really want a Global S3 bucket - why oh why has amazon set up regions!!

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the answer. That's exactly what CloudFront is for.

Its pretty trivial to 'link' CloudFront to your bucket, which then means your content is served from multiple edge locations around the world.

Like S3, you can public or private ditributions and you can [now](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=956) use the new [Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) to protect your content too.